# Logarithm of a transcendental number

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-numbers

Can anything be said about the nature of the number $\log y $ where $y $ is a transcendental number not of the form $y=e^x $ or written trivially in that form using $x=\log w $ for some $w $ transcendental? Would the result always be transcendental? Just considering real numbers here.

Comment: What is $x$ here?

Comment: Every positive real number is of the form $e^x$.

Comment: You've updated the post but the answer is still the same.  ln of negative numbers require complex analysis and are not real.  *All* non-negative numbers are of the the form $y = e^x$ and *ALL* real numbers are "trivially" x = ln w for some w.  There are *NO* real numbers that aren't.   What are you having trouble accepting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can be said about $\ln y$ where $y$ is not of the form $y = e^x$?

That such a value can never exist. Because only negative numbers aren't of the form $y = e^x$ and the natural logs of negative numbers don't exist.

Is it always transcendental?

No, it is never transcendental because it never exists.

If $y$ is non-negative and it's not of the form $y = e^x; x$ not transcendental?  Is that always transcendental?

Yes.  If $y$ is not of the form $y = e^x; x$ not transcendental then $y$ is of the form $y = e^x; x$ *is* transcendental, so $\ln y = x$ is transcendental.

Comment: As an example to hopefully clarify (or possibly get wrong further)... What about $\log y $ where $y=\pi $. Here $y $ is transcendental. I don't allow/consider rewriting as $y=e^{\log\pi}$ which is what I meant in the question. Is $\log\pi $ transcendental ? What about if $t$ is some other transcendental number which I don't allow/consider rewriting in the form $t=e^x $. Will $\log t $ always be transcendental ?

Comment: You have a naive notion that numbers have some predefining.  log pi is transcendental (I'm pretty sure).  Most numbers are transcendental so most log x = y will be both x and y transcendental.  You seem to think $y = e^x; x$ algebraic and therefore log y = x algebraic is a "trick".  It isn't.  There is a one to one coorespondence between all positive y and all real log y.  So every f@@@ing y *is* of the form $e^x$ and ln y is trancendental if and only if x is transcendental.  Trivially.  And that's all there is to it.  (to be continued..)

Comment: I think what you are really asking is: "Is there any relation between the transcendency of y and of ln y"  (which is equivalent to "any relation between x and $e^x$").  In particular is it ever the case that y and ln y are both algebraic?  Obviously y = 1 and ln y = 0 is one.  I don't think there are any other.  You want to know if y is trans does that always imply that ln y is trans.  Obviously this is not the case as for *every single algebraic* x there is an $e^x$ and so far as we know so far all but one are trans.  So ln y is algebraic  That is *not* a trick. so ... to be cont...

Comment: --conclusion... The real two questions are:  If x $\ne$ 0 x not transcendental, is $e^x$ always transcendental?  (I think it is but I don't want to go on a limb.  I think Taylor series assures it.) And conversely.  If y $\ne 1$; y not transcendental, is log y always transcendental?  This is actually an equivalent question that means the same and has the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every positive number is of the form $y=e^x$ for some $x$, and negative numbers do not have logarithms.

Comment: I'm assuming he/she is excluding $y=e^x$ with $x$ not transcendental...

Comment: @bartgol I don't want to make that kind of assumption and would prefer if OP explicitly writes down their assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

No. $e$ is transcendental and $\log e = 1$.

And every positive real number $y$ can be written as $e^x$ for some $x$ (specifically $x=\log y$).

Comment: He/she is explicitly excluding numbers of the form $y=e^x$ (I'm assuming with $x$ not transcendental).

Comment: @bartgol If $y=e^x$ with $x$ not transcendental, then $\log y = x$ is not transcendental...

Comment: Was about to comment that, I just think OP didn't think the question enough before asking it, haha.

Comment: Good point. I guess the question appeared deeper, but in the end is kind of a tautology...